# Chrome browser and Javascript alert box

Tags: javascript

My web application uses alert and confirm boxes to display information when a link is clicked.

All browsers display these boxes properly except for Chrome. When I click on a link in Chrome, all I get is the box displayed with one word "Javascript" inside.

It has to work correctly in all browsers, even if the box displayed is constructed a little different in each. It barely works in IE but it does work and if you are going to use that crippled excuse for a browser, you deserve it! ;)

I didn't think this simple problem required a demo in jsfiddle and every one knows what an alert or confirm box looks like, nevertheless if someone needs more clarification please don't just not answer at all, but let me know.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Hello Paul, Welcome to StackOverflow.
Can we see some code? what have you tried?

Comment: This is a repost of an earlier question by yourself. please don't do that, rather just edit your original question.
Also, if you can't figure out how to highlight code, ask around in the chat, or take some time to read the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

well alert box is a browser component, therefore all browser vendor uses their own implementation. Since you want same result on all browser, the best you can do is use your own code to produce the result like using modalpopup which will be static around all browser

Comment: Well I run out of room trying to explain. I guess my the best option is to copy the question and move it to Devshed. This site has the most user-unfriendlist software!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure cross platform and cross browser compatibility i would use something like:

[jQuery Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Would be alot handier and ensure it looks/works the same everywhere.

Please note jQuery is just an example and any other alert/confirm like JavaScript/CSS would do the job just don't rely on the browser!

Please also note that browsers can change there implementation at any time leaving you stuck if you dont use your own!